# how to express a variable as a percentage?

Tags: c

i have the following function:

```
void BCC_AH_COUNT(bcc_drv_config_t* const drvConfig, bcc_cid_t cid, uint32_t *currentCapacity)
{
    extern int32_t isenseCurrentMA;

    printf("current equals: %li  mA \n", isenseCurrentMA);

    *currentCapacity = *currentCapacity-(isenseCurrentMA/3600);

    printf("current SOC is: %li mAh \n", *currentCapacity);


}
```

the `uint32_t currentCapacity` is defined as a global variable and given the value `105000` at the beginning of the main function.
every time the above function is run, the `currentCapacity` gets updated and that works as it should.

now i want to express the `currentCapacity` as a percentage from 0 to 100, where `100%` should be `105000` and `0%` should be `0`.
how would i go about this, i think i should start by making a new variable called `currentSOC` which would then have a value ranging from 0 to 100.

Comment: for integer math,  `full=105000;  percent = (latest_reading * 100) / full)`; does that work for you?

Comment: `isenseCurrentMA` --> looks like "isenseCurrent_mega_amps". ;-)  Maybe `isenseCurrent_mA` instead?

Comment: @thebusybee From a math stand-point yes, yet the subtleties of integer vs FP conversion and division come into play.  Notice how `*currentCapacity-(isenseCurrentMA/3600);` truncates (Incorrect usage here IMO) here rather than rounds

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right:

```
double SOC = 100 * *currentCapacity / 105000.;
// Now, SOC will hold values like 66.666 (representing 66.666%)
```

---

```
void BCC_AH_COUNT(bcc_drv_config_t* const drvConfig, bcc_cid_t cid, uint32_t *currentCapacity)
{
    extern int32_t isenseCurrentMA;
    printf("current equals: %li  mA \n", isenseCurrentMA);

    *currentCapacity = *currentCapacity-(isenseCurrentMA/3600);
    printf("current Capacity is: %li mAh \n", *currentCapacity);

    double SOC = 100 * *currentCapacity / 105000.;
    printf("The State of Charge is %.3f %%\n", SOC);
}
```

Comment: when i use the code you provided, the console does not print the value of SOC, i tried changing it from a double to a uint32_t and then it works but i do like to have it print 100.000 instead of 100.     output from console: current equals: 0  mA 
current capacity is: 105000 mAh 
The State of Charge is  %

Comment: abelenky, the subtlety of employing `double` math in the division would be more clear with `/ 105000.0` than `/ 105000.`.

Comment: @longleggedlemon:  Show the exact code you tried.  I think its likely you have a typo.

Comment: i copied the code you posted, so it is 100% the same. i tried using %lf but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate percentage, you want to do:

currentValue/maxValue * 100

However, you are working with integers, so 
currentValue/maxValue will give you zero, unless you are over 100%.

So...multiply by 100 *first*.

(currentValue * 100) / maxValue.

In your actual function, you would need a variable (a #define or a const variable, ideally) which is equal to your max value.

Then:

```
const uint32_t maxCapacity = 105000;
uint32_t percentCapacity = (*currentCapacity * 100) / maxCapacity;
```

Comment: I like this integer only approach.  Yet since the division truncates the quotient and inexact physical quantities are more informative when rounded,  code could form a rounded result with `percentCapacity = (*currentCapacity * 100 + maxCapacity/2) / maxCapacity;`.  I am also leary of changing this to unsigned given `*currentCapacity-(isenseCurrentMA/3600)` might go negative.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- currentCapacity is unsigned.  You are correct, though, that this mixing of signed and unsigned could be problematic.

Comment: Good point.  Yet `isenseCurrentMA` is signed.  I see a recipe for troubles when `*currentCapacity` is less than `isenseCurrentMA/3600`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I agree.  There are problems in the original code that I am not solving.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate as a percentage is fairly easy, scale by 100.0.

Yet this task has issues:

- Is floating point available and/or something to be avoided?
- Should output round, rather than truncate, to the nearest representable value?
- What to do when percentage is out of range?
- What to do when `*currentCapacity` is less than `isenseCurrentMA/3600`?
- How many decimal places for the percentage?

---

Below avoids FP, rounds (3 decimal places for %) and detects negative range.  Untested.

```
void BCC_AH_COUNT(bcc_drv_config_t* const drvConfig, bcc_cid_t cid, uint32_t *currentCapacity) {
    (void) drvConfig; // parameter not used
    extern int32_t isenseCurrentMA;

    printf("current equals: %" PRIi32 "  mA \n", isenseCurrentMA);  // Corrected specifier

    int32_t amp_scale = 3600;
    int32_t delta_cap_round = isenseCurrentMA < 0 ? -amp_scale : amp_scale;
    int32_t delta_cap = (isenseCurrentMA + delta_cap_round/2)/amp_scale; // rounded delta
    // Two stage compare as delta_cap, *currentCapacity differ in type sign-ness. 
    if (delta_cap > 0 && delta_cap > *currentCapacity) {
      // *currentCapacity should go below 0, yet as it is unsigned, best to do is floor it.
      // A better solution would be to change type to int32_t *currentCapacity.
      *currentCapacity = 0;
    } else
      *currentCapacity -= delta_cap;
    }
    printf("current SOC is: %" PRIu32 " mAh \n", *currentCapacity); // Corrected specifier

    // 100% should be 105000 and 0% should be 0
    uint64_t n_scale = 100*1000L; // scale to thousands of %
    uint32_t d_scale = 105000;
    uint32_t cap_percentage = (n_scale * *currentCapacity + scale/2)/scale; // form rounded value 

    // print without FP
    char buf[11]; // Big enough for any uint32_t
    int len = sprintf(buf, "%04" PRIu32, cap_percentage); // at least 4 digits.
    printf("Percentage: %.*s.%s%%\n", len - 3, buf, &buf[len - 3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression will be `(*currentCapacity) * 100 / maxCapacity` where `maxCapacity` has the value `105000`, but you do not want to hard-code this constant value in your function because you clearly have it available in the main function as you are using it to initialise `*currentCapacity` there, and you don't want the same constant to be defined in more than one place.

So you probably want to pass it through as another argument to your function, and probably as call by value because you don't need to modify it inside `BCC_AH_COUNT`:

```
void BCC_AH_COUNT(bcc_drv_config_t* const drvConfig, bcc_cid_t cid,
                  uint32_t *currentCapacity, uint32_t maxCapacity)
```

Alternatively if it is a compile-time constant, then you would put something like

```
#define MAXCAPACITY 105000
```

into your header file, and use that where it is needed, after `#include`-ing your header file.